# Generate xml document from wsdl s:complexType

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have wsdl document and inside I have

```
<wsdl:types>
<s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.webserviceX.NET">
<s:element name="GetWeather">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CityName" type="s:string"/>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetWeatherResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetWeatherResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCitiesByCountry">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CountryName" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="GetCitiesByCountryResponse">
<s:complexType>
<s:sequence>
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetCitiesByCountryResult" type="s:string"/>
</s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
</s:element>
<s:element name="string" nillable="true" type="s:string"/>
</s:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

I want to generate xml document as my template from `<s:element name="GetWeather">` and populate it with data. After wrap it to  SOAP:Envilope and sent to ws server.
How can I do this using JAX-WS api.
Please help me to understand.